# How to find all files whose contents belong to $PATH?

Tags: path

When I enter `$PATH` in terminal in Debian 11, I see there are several contents are the same. I checked the file of `/etc/profile` and `~/.bashrc`, which even don't contain some contents of the output of `$PATH`.

1. Where is the contents those weren't  in `/etc/profile` and `~/.bashrc`,
2. How to find all files whose contents component the output of `$PATH`?
3. How should I ensure that the contents of the output of `$PATH` not repetitive?

Thanks.

Comment: 1 and 2.`grep -rw PATH= /` 3. What for? It doesn't slow down anything.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov `grep -rw PATH= /` find too much information, in which most are useless. 3. It has no mean to repeat paths. I just want to find where it come from.

Comment: What I would do: `# grep -lrw 'PATH=' /etc /home/me`

Comment: @GillesQuénot The `# grep -lrw 'PATH=' /etc /home/me` exports nothing in my Debian 11.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a surefire way to find out how and where the `$PATH` variable gets populated from. First install `strace` if it's not installed (`sudo apt install strace`).

1. Find any unused getty process, there might be none:

`pgrep agetty`

2. If there are none, press Ctrl + Alt + F4, this will create one.
3. Now run this command under root anywhere else, e.g. in your graphical session (return to it using Alt + F1 or Alt + F7).

```
sudo strace -e file --string-limit=500 -f -o /tmp/login.log -p `pgrep agetty`
```

4. Press Ctrl + Alt + F4 and login. Do not do anything else.
5. Kill the strace process by pressing Ctrl + C.

Now you can inspect the `/tmp/login.log` file for any files your shell has opened. You could now `grep` them all and find where the PATH variable is getting defined/redefined.

Comment: In step 3, the ```sudo strace -e file -string-limit=500 -f -o /tmp/login.log -p `pgrep agetty`
``` exports `strace: invalid -s argument: 'tring-limit=500' Try 'strace -h' for more information.`

Comment: `--string-limit`, not `-string-limit`, sorry. I normally use a short argument but decided to make it verbose for beauty and while copying, missed a dash.

Comment: There is a new information: ```strace: option requires an argument -- 'p'
Try 'strace -h' for more information.```. What the mean of this information?

Comment: You may not yet be running a single `agetty` instance. Please check whether `pgrep agetty` returns anything. Your system may also use something different. Please run `ps fax | egrep 'tty[0-9]' | grep -v X` to see what process is responsible for console. If its name is not `agetty` replace the `agetty` above with the proper process name or simply specify the PID `-p NUMBER`.

Comment: Thanks. `less login.log | grep PATH` outputs: ```15825 execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/env -i PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin run-parts --lsbsysinit /etc/update-motd.d > /run/motd.dynamic.new"], 0x5587c49372f0 /* 3 vars */) = 0
15826 execve("/usr/bin/env", ["/usr/bin/env", "-i", "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin", "run-parts", "--lsbsysinit", "/etc/update-motd.d"], 0x56438c16f788 /* 4 vars */) = 0```. From these, I can't tell where the PATH is defined.

Comment: All contents are here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkYaWBjatjEIgbgKqA7ybfT3X1TCYQ?e=Jiz9Xu